# Where can I find the offline installer of Google Chrome for the Mac?

Tags: mac, installation, google-chrome

..It's easy to find the offline installer for windows machines: http://support.google.com/installer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=126299

However I need to install Chrome on a Mac which has no connection to the Internet.

Can anyone help? It seems like this should be an easy one but I have been surprisingly unsuccessful!

Kind Regards,
Luke

Comment: You can't possibly be serious.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: If he's using Windows or Linux, he won't find the link anywhere on the Google Chrome website. For me, even the download links included in the Mac installation instructions point to the Linux download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `?platform=mac` to the end of the Google Chrome download page's URL:

https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/?platform=mac

The download is in the form of a [DMG file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Disk_Image), a disk image containing the Google Chrome app. Installation (as with many Mac apps) merely consists of double-clicking the disk image to mount it and then dragging the app into the system's Applications folder.

Comment: Thanks @PleaseStand, it's pretty bizarre that Google hides this from Windows clients - much appreciated!

Comment: The link isn't up to date any more, use https://www.google.com/chrome/?platform=mac&standalone=1 .